# Integrating Dynamics CRM SDK with ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, dynamics-crm-4

I have recently been reading up on the MVC tutorials on [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/mvc) and most if not all of the tutorials use Entity Framework and DbContext to perform CRUD operations on data.

I'm planning to create an ASP MVC application which uses Dynamics CRM 4 as the data store.
With this in mind, where would the best place be to write the logic to perform CRUD operations using the CRM SDK, the Model, the Controller or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would encourage you to encapsulate all of the CRM data-access logic in a separate layer/assembly that would then be consumed by your controller(s). Those tutorials shouldn't really be doing database communication directly from the controllers, either, regardless of using EF/DbContext.  Or they should at least point out a better way of organizing things.

Comment: Some of the later tutorials do separate the DB logic from the controller in a repository, until just now I thought that this was also part of the Entity Framework but apparently not.  It makes sense for the SDK logic to into this abstraction layer:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application